# Python pandas DataFrame - Keep rows that have same information in 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

If have a python DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    ID_1    ID_2    haplotypeID  locus
    A1  A1  hap.1.1  KIRa
    A1  A1  hap.1.2  KIRa
    A2  A2  hap.2.1  KIRa
    A2  A2  hap.2.2  KIRa
    A3  A3  hap.1.1  KIRa
    A4  A4  hap.2.2  KIRa
    A4  A4  hap.1.2  KIRa
    A1  A1  hap.1.1  KIRb
    A2  A2  hap.2.1  KIRb
    A2  A2  hap.2.2  KIRb
    A3  A3  hap.1.1  KIRb
    A3  A3  hap.1.2  KIRb
    A4  A4  hap.2.2  KIRb
    A4  A4  hap.1.2  KIRb
    A1  A1  hap.1.1  KIRc
    A2  A2  hap.2.1  KIRc
    A3  A3  hap.1.1  KIRc
    A3  A3  hap.1.2  KIRc
    A4  A4  hap.1.2  KIRc
```

There are 4 columns named: ID_1, ID_2, haplotype ID and locus. 
I would like to keep only the pairs of rows that are duplicated for the 3 columns ID_1, ID_2, and locus. In the example above, the output would thereby look like this:

```
    ID_1    ID_2    haplotypeID  locus
    A1  A1  hap.1.1  KIRa
    A1  A1  hap.1.2  KIRa
    A2  A2  hap.2.1  KIRa
    A2  A2  hap.2.2  KIRa
    A4  A4  hap.2.2  KIRa
    A4  A4  hap.1.2  KIRa
    A2  A2  hap.2.1  KIRb
    A2  A2  hap.2.2  KIRb
    A3  A3  hap.1.1  KIRb
    A3  A3  hap.1.2  KIRb
    A4  A4  hap.2.2  KIRb
    A4  A4  hap.1.2  KIRb
    A3  A3  hap.1.1  KIRc
    A3  A3  hap.1.2  KIRc
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This indicates how to drop the duplicates while I want to keep them. The tool I was looking for is "keep=False".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df[['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'locus']].duplicated(keep=False)]
Out[449]: 
   ID_1 ID_2 haplotypeID locus
0    A1   A1     hap.1.1  KIRa
1    A1   A1     hap.1.2  KIRa
2    A2   A2     hap.2.1  KIRa
3    A2   A2     hap.2.2  KIRa
5    A4   A4     hap.2.2  KIRa
6    A4   A4     hap.1.2  KIRa
8    A2   A2     hap.2.1  KIRb
9    A2   A2     hap.2.2  KIRb
10   A3   A3     hap.1.1  KIRb
11   A3   A3     hap.1.2  KIRb
12   A4   A4     hap.2.2  KIRb
13   A4   A4     hap.1.2  KIRb
16   A3   A3     hap.1.1  KIRc
17   A3   A3     hap.1.2  KIRc
```

Or,

```
df[df.duplicated(['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'locus'], keep=False)]
```

`df.duplicated(['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'locus'])` or `df[['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'locus']].duplicated()` returns a boolean array. Corresponding elements are True for the duplicated entries (by default, [only the first ones](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)). By passing `keep=False` you can make all duplicated to have True values. The rest is boolean indexing.